# Git: ignore group of modified files after a build

Tags: git, github, build

I have a build script which clones a repo from GitHub and then does some modifications on a few files which are already tracked.

When I type 'git status' it shows these files as modified, but I would like git to think these files are not modified as I don't want to add them to the staging area.

For example, after my build I have modified files that reside in different folders:

```
config.dat
database/storage.sqlite
code/conf.pyc
```

I know a manual way telling git to assume these are unchanged by hard-coding with the files names like:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config.dat
git update-index --assume-unchanged database/storage.sqlite
git update-index --assume-unchanged code/conf.pyc
```

Is there a way to loop through all modified files and perform this operation --assume-unchanged operation on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ls-files` to list the modified files and pipe it into `update-index`

```
git ls-files -m | xargs git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

Comment: @WilliamRoss Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Use * to represent all files in the directory which you want to ignore.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [file-path]/*
```

Comment: I may not know all the file-paths in advance. When I tried do 'git update-index --assume-unchanged *' it says 'fatal: Unable to mark file {folder}' where {folder} is the name of the first folder alphabetically showing up in that path. Is there another way to loop through all of the files programmatically?